# Enhancing profile results in an unexpected error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

My userpage on Stack Overflow asks me to enhance my profile. The continue button does not work, regardless of my input:

[image]

Comment: Anything logged in the console?

Answer (score 31):

This has now been fixed and pushed to production.

Basically, we replaced usages of `==` with `===` on the javascript and forgot to also update the way we render the steps for the Enhance Your Profile box. Clicking on `Continue` should take you to the next step, but no valid steps were found (as steps comparison was failing) and an error message was displayed.

Thanks for your report <3

Comment: OMG you do not use `===` from the start??? I always use *two* `===` comparisons to make sure that the comparison is working properly...

Comment: Everyone knows you're supposed to use `====`, which [requires both objects to submit a DNA sample to prove they're the same](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=29430381#29430381)/